# Postgres query plan changes for identical query when using pg_hint_plan

Tags: postgresql, pg-hint-plan

(Postgres 11.7)

I'm using the `Rows` `pg_hint_plan` hint to dynamically fix a bad row-count estimate.

My query accepts an array of arguments, which get `unnest`ed and joined onto the rest of the query as a predicate. By default, the query planner always assumes this array-argument contains 100 records, whereas in reality this number could be very different. This bad estimate was resulting in poor query plans. I set the number of rows definitively from within the calling application, by changing the hint text per query.

This approach seems to work *sometimes*, but I see some strange behaviour testing the query (in DBeaver).

If I start with a brand new connection, when I `explain` the query (or indeed just run it), the hint seems to be ignored for the **first 6 executions**, but thereafter it starts getting interpreted correctly. This is consistently reproducible: I see the offending row count estimates change on the 7th execution on a new connection.

More interestingly, the query also uses some (`immutable`) functions to do some lookup operations. If I *remove* these and replace them with an equivalent CTE or sub-select, this strange behaviour seems to disappear, and the hints are evaluated correctly all the time, even on a brand new connection.

What could be causing it to not honour the `pg_hint_plan` hints until after 6 requests have been made in that session? Why does the presence of the functions have a bearing on the hints?

Comment: Are you using the JDBC driver and prepared statements?

Comment: JDBC driver yes. I'm not explicitly preparing the statements, no.

(thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using JDBC, try setting the `prepareThreshold` connection parameter to 1, as detailed in [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/server-prepare.html).

That will make the driver use a server prepared statement as soon as possible, ond it seems like this extension only works in that case.

Comment: Thanks: so `prepareThreshold` was set to 5. I tried changing it to 1 (and also 0 - disable preparation) but the behaviour remained the same.

Comment: Then it may have to do with custom plans in PostgreSQL. If you have PostgreSQL v12 or better, try setting `plan_cache_mode` to `force_generic_plan`.

Comment: We're only on 11.7 currently, but I may be able to upgrade and test it... Thank you

Comment: `force_generic_plan` is not necessary, it works with custom plans too, but extended protocol is necessary (too bad it's not mentioned in the documentation)

Comment: It might also be the bug https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan/issues/145 in pg_hint_plan where one unhinted prepared statement might set a false state and subsequent hinted queries are ignored.

This is fixed in the current version, but at the time of writing the unpatched version is deployed on AWS RDS.

Workaround is setting prepareThreshold to zero